Multiplication in negative fractional Sobolev spaces
Let $f\in H^s$, where
$$ H^s(R)=\{u\in S'(R)~ \text{such that}~ (1+k^2)^{s/2} F(u(k))\in L^2(R)\}$$
where $s<0$, $S'$ is the space of tempered distributions and $F(\cdot)$ denotes the Fourier transform.
Further, let g be a smooth function.
Then what is the meaning of product of  functions $f$ and $g$ (i.e. $fg$) and in which space '$fg$' belong?
Further, what type of function $g$ we should choose so that the product '$fg$' is in $H^s$ ?

I just edited a little to clean up TeX-related issues...

Thanks @paulgarrett for edit. I think I have found an article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.07379  (Theorem 8.1 ) related to the question.

Since no one else has responded: what is your context? One way of thinking about this is in terms of the "trace theorem", applied to $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ and restricting to the diagonal $\mathbb R$... Would such an approach be satisfactory for you?

@paulgarrett Could you please explain it little bit more? It will be helpful if you provide some example like if we take our f and g both as a dirac delta ( $\delta $ )
which lies in $H^s$ for $ s=-1/2+\epsilon$, then what is the meaning of $\delta\times \delta$  and in which space it will be? Generally,  I know that  $\delta$  is a distribution and if I am correct then the product of distribution is not defined.

I don't think this answer is optimal or universal, but I can confirm that it is correct... as far as it goes... And is easily verifiable! :)
Considering Fourier series in two variables, $f(x,y) = \sum_{m,n} c_{m,n}e^{2\pi i(mx+ny)}$, the $s$th Sobolev space $H^s$ is the Hilbert space of such series with $\sum_{m,n} (1+m^2+n^2)^s\cdot |c_{m,n}|^2 < +\infty$.
It's elementary that $H^{{1\over 2}+\varepsilon}$ restricts to the one-variable $H^{\varepsilon'}$ ... for $\varepsilon>0$! Otherwise, there's no (straightforward) restriction theorem. Nevermind "wave-front sets"...
"Multiplication" $f\cdot g$ of elements of the single-variable $H^s$ can/should be construed as restriction of $f\otimes g$ to the diagonal... So, in general, there's no systematic multiplication, except for $H^{{1\over 2}+}$, which maps to $H^{0+}$. Certainly sharper (more technical) things do hold.
EDIT: after thinking intermittently for some days, I realized that, yes, CERTAINLY, there is a $H^\infty$-module structure on $H^{-\infty}$, coming from an $H^\infty$ structure on $H^k$ for all $k\in \mathbb Z$. In tangible cases, this is nearly immediate from the obvious estimates on derivatives (with sup-norm estimates on $H^\infty$), and then some dualization, if desired. I'd simply not ever thought about the unsymmetric case! :)
(Similarly this can be refined to various $H^m$-module structures on $H^n$, depending on dimension, etc.)

So, in general, there's no systematic multiplication'',  but in this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.07379 , if $g\in C_c^\infty$ , then there is a product rule, see theorem 8.1 and inequality 8.1.
